# php variable loss at end of program

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I had asked a question before relating to what I believed to be the issue with my program, but was wrong in my assumption.  So no, this is not a repeat of the same question.  I had thought that I was using include() because a value wasn't being sent over, but through debugging I saw that the value of the variable was being lost directly after an if statement(the variable in question being $un):

```
if(trim($un) != '' && trim($pw) != '' && $password == $pw)
{

    include "problem.html";

}
```

The if statement is at the end of the php file, but I need a variable from this file in another file.  How would I go about this?

Comment: "the value of the variable was being lost directly after an if statement" : Did you try putting `echo $un` immediately before and immediately after the if statement?

Comment: Do you need to save the variable so it can be accessed from a later request?  If the variable is global, it would be available in another file, but it has to be defined by that file first.  Maybe you need [sessions](http://php.net/sessions)

Comment: Yes I echoed, it held the value before and in the if statement.  Not after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this on include() and require()

> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

or using $_POST or $_GET

> http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=php_passing_variables.php

Answer (score 0):

*Hi Sam,*

You have at least two ways to go. Session or params. I will explain to you how to you the two ways to get your var on the other side. :0

```
if(trim($un) != '' && trim($pw) != '' && $password == $pw)
{

    # Start a new session
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['UN'] = $un;

    # include the other page
    include "problem.html";   // change your page to php extension

}
```

Change your `problem.html` to `problem.ph`p

and add this line in the begining of the file

```
session_start();
```

now call your session and see the result

```
echo $_SESSION['UN'];
```

when finish the use of this **SESSION** var, just unset it using `unset()` function.

I hope this help you out.